# What am I? Newest fun riddle

Tags: riddle

I am going to do it how I want and when I want. I know everything and I don't need your help. I'm here when you need me, maybe. What I am?

Comment: Hi Kate, and welcome to Puzzling! I fear this question may be waaaayy too broad to have a single provably correct answer and that this kind of question will result in lots of "It's valid, but not what I was thinking of..." answers. Is there any way you can limit the riddle still further, to help people hone in on the true answer without going down lots of dead ends? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> Teenager

Explanation:

> Is any needed?

Comment: Love it! But the question is "What am I?" not "Who am I?"